# Creating a book class

Tags: java, string, class, constructor

With 5 fields  title -
String, the title of the book.
Author - String, the author of the book.
Pages - integer, the number of pages in the book.
Publisher - String, the publisher of the book.
Year - integer, the year the book was published.

With 6 methods
A constructor that accepts as arguments the values for the fields above, in the order listed.
A copy constructor that makes a copy of a Book object.
A getTitle method that returns the value of the title field.
A setAuthor method that accepts a String argument, which is used to set the author field.
An equals method that returns a boolean indicating if two objects contain the same information. If they do, it returns true, false otherwise. The objects contain the same information when their fields contain the same values.
A toString method that returns a String that contains on separate lines (5 lines), the names and values for each field.
Demonstrate the class in a program. Demo program is required to:
Create at least two Book objects.
Create a copy of a Book object.
Use each of the other four methods to show they work properly.  Do not explicitly call the toString method in your demo program.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: You need to provide the code that you have tried. Have a look at this guide - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for class Book. In `toString` method there is `String.format` method which makes readable string. Nothing more special.
When `equals` method is overridden then `hashCode` method should be too. They both compare objects if they are equals. You can find it more for example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java).

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int pages;
    private String publisher;
    private int year;

    public Book(String title, String author, int pages, String publisher, int year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Book(Book book) {
        this.title = book.title;
        this.author = book.author;
        this.pages = book.pages;
        this.publisher = book.publisher;
        this.year = book.year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Book)) {
            return false;
        }
        Book other = (Book) o;
        
        if (this.title.equals(other.title) &&
                this.author.equals(other.author) &&
                this.publisher.equals(other.publisher) &&
                this.pages == other.pages && this.year == other.year) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-10s %s\n", "Title:", title) +
            String.format("%-10s %s\n", "Author:", author) +
            String.format("%-10s %d\n", "Pages:", pages) +
            String.format("%-10s %s\n", "Publisher:", publisher) +
            String.format("%-10s %d", "Year:", year);
    }

}
```

Here is main class which uses all of the methods.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book first = new Book("The Book", "Famous Writer", 199, "Big Book Publisher", 1984);
        Book second = new Book("The Second Book", "Less F. Writer", 249, "The Book Publishers", 1999);

        System.out.println("First book");
        System.out.println(first + "\n");
        System.out.println("Second book");
        System.out.println(second + "\n");

        System.out.println("Title of the first book: " + first.getTitle() + "\n");


        Book firstCopy = new Book(first);
        System.out.println("Copy of the first book:");
        System.out.println(firstCopy + "\n");

        System.out.println("Copy equals first book: " + firstCopy.equals(first));
        System.out.println("Second book equals first book: " + second.equals(first));
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Change writer of the copy to :'Most F. Writer'");
        firstCopy.setAuthor("Most F. Writer");
        System.out.println(firstCopy + "\n");
        System.out.println("Copy equals first book: " + firstCopy.equals(first));

    }

}
```

When executed main class outputs this:

```
First book
Title:     The Book
Author:    Famous Writer
Pages:     199
Publisher: Big Book Publisher
Year:      1984

Second book
Title:     The Second Book
Author:    Less F. Writer
Pages:     249
Publisher: The Book Publishers
Year:      1999

Title of the first book: The Book

Copy of the first book:
Title:     The Book
Author:    Famous Writer
Pages:     199
Publisher: Big Book Publisher
Year:      1984

Copy equals first book: true
Second book equals first book: false

Change writer of the copy to :'Most F. Writer'
Title:     The Book
Author:    Most F. Writer
Pages:     199
Publisher: Big Book Publisher
Year:      1984

Copy equals first book: false
```